# I can't deploy to the device in Xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, deployment

Xcode doesn't let me choose "Device". I only deploy to simulator, to iPad 3.2. Organizer tells me: "XCode cannot find the software image to install this version" when I connect an iPhone 3.1.3 firmware.

I have Xcode 3.2.5 with iOS 4.2. What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is XCode has no idea about version of iOS that you have running on your device. You need to do following:

1. In Organizer see what exact version of iOS is on your device (say it's '3.1.3 ABC')
2. Open terminal and go to `/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/`
3. There you will see list of OS images that XCode has. You need to pick on that is 'closer' to one that you have on the device (say you have directory there called 3.1) and create a symbolic link like:
   `ln -s 3.1 3.1.3\ ABC`.
4. This way you fool XCode to think that it knows exact version of your device.

Comment: I am facing the same problem, I tried this, but nothing happens. I mean, I created the symbolic link with a folder named `3.1.3 (7E18)` but it still won't work.

Comment: Did you restart XCode after that?

Comment: Can u post a screenshot from Orginizer saying that it can't work with device with some specific version and what do you get when you list available platforms in terminal?

Answer (score -2):

You need to upgrade your phone to 4.2, because you can only deploy to iphone versions where you have the sdk from.

Comment: You can test on phones with older firmware.

Comment: BTW, it says that it cannot find the software image, but that does not matter, just install the right provisioning profile, and you can build and run!